# XSLT Variables and Choose/Otherwise not working right

Tags: xslt

I have some XSLT that looks like:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string(//User[@UserID = $UserID]/ROOT/Prop[@Nm = 'GreaseBoardCategory'])">
        <xsl:variable name="Type" select="concat('Documenter', //User[@UserID = $UserID]/ROOT/Prop[@Nm = 'GreaseBoardCategory'])"/>                         
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:variable name="Type" select="concat('Documenter', user:GetUserType(string(//Payload/@SiteID), string(@UserID)))"/>                         
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

And I want to assign a variable to it called "Type" I see from other examples that I should be doing this instead:

```
<xsl:variable name="Type">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string(//User[@UserID = $UserID]/ROOT/Prop[@Nm = 'GreaseBoardCategory'])">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('Documenter', //User[@UserID = $UserID]/ROOT/Prop[@Nm = 'GreaseBoardCategory'])"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('Documenter', user:GetUserType(string(//Payload/@SiteID), string(@UserID)))"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

But my variable is NOT getting set. It should hit the Otherwise block but never does. Any ideas? It doesn't get set to anything..

The only way to get Type to be set is to do away with the Choose/When/Otherwise statements and just pick one of the two options, like:

```
<xsl:variable name="Type" select="concat('Documenter', //User[@UserID = $UserID]/ROOT/Prop[@Nm = 'GreaseBoardCategory'])"/>
```

for example.

Comment: What does VBScript (in question title) have to do with this?

Comment: If it doesn't hit `xsl:otherwise`, then it means that condition for `xsl:when` is satisfied, and you should look into that specifically. Without seeing the input XML, not much else can be said.

Comment: thanks for the heads up about the title. Well, it doesn't hit either the When or the Otherwise, because I pass $Type into a VB procedure that spits the value of many variables out, and there's nothing there at all for Type.

Comment: Unless I explicitly set Type to be either the When or Otherwise statement's select value will Type have a value.

So if I do away with all of the When/Otherwise business and just say:

<xsl:variable name="Type" select="concat('Documenter', user:GetUserType(string(//Payload/@SiteID), string(@UserID)))"/>

Then it gets set correctly. Only in the When/Otherwise blocks does it not get set to anything.

Comment: There are two possibilities here, then. Either the value produced by either branch of `xsl:choose` is empty, or your VB code is wrong. Again, this needs input XML, and the VB code used to display `$Type`, to tell for sure.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your last comment while writing my own. So you've used the `xsl:value-of` from the "otherwise" branch for a test; what if you use the one from "when"?

Comment: using either the When or Otherwise branch to set my variable explicitly produces 1) "DocumenterPhysician" and 2) "Documenter", respectively.

Comment: moreover, i use a VB function that spits out a SQL query. The SQL query that shows up in my output window looks like "EXEC dbo.InsertPerson @blah='blah', @blah2='blah2', @Type='Documenter', @blah3='blah3'

BUT, when I use the choose/otheriwse/when block, my SQL statement oddly enough looks like dbo.InsertPerson @blah='blah', @blah2='blah2', @blah3='blah3'

Where did the string text "@Type='" & Type & "', @blah3=..." go???! it makes no sense why this is happening. the string text should be there with no parameter if nothing got set..

Comment: If you won't post the VBScript there's not much we can do.  We can't just guess what you're doing in code you haven't shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out. The problem was in how I was accessing the XSLT variable Type.. I originally had:

```
<xsl:value-of select="user:InsertPerson($SiteID, $VisitGUID, $ID, $FirstName, $MiddleName, $LastName, $Address1, $Address2, $City, $State, $Zipcode, $Degree, $SSN, $Phone1, $Phone2, $Priority, $LogonCategory, $HospitalID, $DocumentCreateTime, $CoSigner, $Type, $Primary, $AddTime)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

But then I changed `"..., $Type, ..."` to `"..., string($Type), ..."` and that fixed it. I'm not sure why out of all the parameters, this is the only one that needed to be wrapped with "string(...)" but it did solve the problem.

Thanks for the help everyonE!

Answer (score 0):

xsl:choose should work as expected. I would recommend that you simplify your example. Say

```
<xsl:value-of select="A"/>
```

in the when-branch and similar say "B" in ther otherwise-branch, instead of your more complex concatenations.

Finally, as others have asked, show us the code where you evaluate variable "Type" and the XML input. The mention of VBScript probably means that you are working with XSLT 1.0. I ask just to make sure.

Comment: Once I create the Type variable, I put it into this:

<xsl:value-of select="user:InsertPerson($SiteID, $VisitGUID, $ID, $FirstName, $MiddleName, $LastName, $Address1, $Address2, $City, $State, $Zipcode, $Degree, $SSN, $Phone1, $Phone2, $Priority, $LogonCategory, $HospitalID, $DocumentCreateTime, $CoSigner, $Type, $Primary, $AddTime)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>

However, when I set the Type variable using the choose/when/otherwise, I get an error. When I set the Type variable expliticly to either When or Otherwise's statement, it works correctly.